# Get all matched row using SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the `posts` table with the following data /structure:

```
posts_id   post_message   u_id  like_count  created
===================================================
1         content.......  1     25          1559041633
2         content.......  2     25          1559041633
```

and `posts_like` table with the following data/structure:

```
like_id    posts_id   u_id   r_id    created
=============================================
22         2          1      2       1559041633
27         2          2      4       1559041633
30         1          2      7       1559041633
```

**Note:** `u_id` means the user id, `r_id` means reaction id, `posts_id` means posts id.

Now, I want to get all posts from the `posts` table along with the full name from the `users` table and **all** `u_id` and `r_id` under each post.

For example, you can see that under `posts_id = 2` I have `u_id` 1 and 2 **and** `r_id` 2 and 4.

**Desire Output:**

```
first post content  
user full Name
u_id: 2
r_id: 7

second post content  
user full Name
u_id: 1, 2
r_id: 2, 4
```

**Current I am using this SQL query**

```
$query = $this->_db->_pdo->prepare("
SELECT p.posts_id, p.post_message, p.like_count, p.created, u.full_name,
 u.u_id, pl.r_id FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.u_id = p.u_id 
LEFT JOIN posts_like AS pl ON pl.posts_id = p.posts_id GROUP BY 
p.posts_id ORDER BY p.posts_id DESC ");
```

This above query does not get the **all** `u_id` and `r_id` under each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP_CONCAT` on your `u_id` and `r_id` fields to get a list of all the reactions. Note that you need to use `pl.u_id`, not `u.u_id` as `u.u_id` refers to the post creator, not the person who has reacted to the post.

```
SELECT p.posts_id, p.post_message, p.like_count, p.created, 
       u.full_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pl.u_id ORDER BY pl.u_id) AS u_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pl.r_id ORDER BY pl.u_id) AS r_id
FROM posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.u_id = p.u_id 
LEFT JOIN posts_like AS pl ON pl.posts_id = p.posts_id 
GROUP BY p.posts_id
ORDER BY p.posts_id DESC
```

Output:

```
posts_id    post_message    like_count  created     full_name   u_id    r_id
2           content.......  25          1559041633  Mary Brown  1,2     2,4
1           content.......  25          1559041633  John Smith  2       7
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWCJ497p1dqK77MaNswJQ9/0)

Comment: Then It's showing me 3 posts but I have 2 posts in the `posts` table.

Comment: @creativeartbd Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. See my edit.

Comment: one more help needed if you can. I want to get the full name corresponding to `u_id`. can I get?

Comment: I get the u_id list and I can use another query to get the full name of this u_id's. but can I get it using the main query?

Comment: @creativeartbd you just need to join to the users table again to get those values. See this fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWCJ497p1dqK77MaNswJQ9/1

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I mistake. I need u_id as well as that u_id's full name too.

Comment: @creativeartbd just add back that value: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWCJ497p1dqK77MaNswJQ9/2

Comment: Again Thanks. :)